# Who does accept JSON body of a post request and automatically parse it and place under main param?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a small action which accepts post requests with json body.

When I post something to this somewhat inside rails automatically parses json and places parse results under main key in params hash.

I would like to know what parts of rails is responsible for that because in all examples I've found online people parsed json bodies by hands. Also it is not somewhat convenient when it comes to testing.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of default middlewares in any Rails app, you can run `rake middleware` to list the ones on your app, the one responsible for parsing the params is, no wonder, `ActionDispatch::ParamsParser`. Check out the [comment](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb) on the corresponding file in the rails repo.

Also, do you mind adding one of those online examples of people parsing json bodies, I've never had to do it. You made me curious :-).

And finally I don't see the issue when testing. You can always send the params as a hash in your RSpec tests if that's what you mean.

Comment: Right now I have to do this `post :create_timeline, {main: { actual_param_goes_here}}` in my tests instead of `post :create_timeline, { actual_param_goes_here}` or even `post :create_timeline , 'json_string'`

Comment: Oh, I see. But I don't really get why you are trying to send the JSON as a string, I mean, instead of doing `post :create_timeline, '{ "timestamp": 2351230 }'` you can simply do `post :create_timeline, { timestamp: 2351230 }. 
The main key is only added if you are doing an ajax call with `data: 'some string'` since there is no way for rails to know that you only want to send one string
If for the needs of your application you need the string representation of the JSON on the server side you will have to do JSON.stringify before making the request to the server or JSON.dump on the server side.

Comment: rails always adds main key no matter how I do a post request (either via browser or curl). I do not get why it does that and why I have to add it manually in tests (see `post :create_timeline, {main: { actual_param_goes_here}}`)

Comment: Do you mind adding either your form or the curl command you are using to test?

Comment: `curl -X POST -H "Cookie: long_session_cookie; path=/; HttpOnly" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '{"name":"abc"}' 'http://localhost:3000/timelines/create'` I've removed long session cookie here

Comment: I just tried that on a new rails app and I didn't get the main key in the params. Rails does parse the string but the params are available directly in params, e.g. params[:name] is "abc".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92628/discussion-between-s-s-j-and-nbermudezs).